# Did the "visited link" color change recently?

Tags: discussion, design

Roses are red, violets are blue,
Normal links are blue, visited links are red.

But has the visited link color changed, very recently? I can't seem to recall it was red. Maybe my memory is weak, though.

And why red anyway? That's way too prominent in my opinion. I don't care that much whether I already saw the link (and question titles are easy to remember), but the red color made me wonder if there was some kind of error, or thing that the system was urging me to check on a few random questions, before I realized the actual reason.

Can we make that color less disruptive (as I'm pretty sure it was some time ago)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it did change. Until a few days ago, the visited links were simply a darker bluish-purple color. I have no idea why the change was made, and I agree, the red is too disruptive.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering whether I simply went nuts. I'm surprised you moderators aren't consulted when the design is about to change, though.

Comment: @DaveTweed:  Thanks for the confirmation.  I noticed it, but wasn't sure if it really changed or if my perception changed.

Comment: I agree. It does not look good.

Answer (score 1):

So, it indeed changed, and several sites have been affected by this (see: [Why are the colors of visited and non-visited links on Academia.SE so different?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344292/why-are-the-colors-of-visited-and-non-visited-links-on-academia-se-so-different)). This is likely due to some tweaks in the CSS (see this answer to: [Code highlighting colors were changed. Intentional or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344241/325443)), and was probably unintentional, which explains why nobody haven't been warned about this change.

In any case, it seems to be fixed now.